# Why does Ignite cluster lag when creating or dropping tables?

Tags: ignite

Ignite lag when Create/Drop table

I have a TRANSACTIONAL table in ignite cluster and an app which runs 8 instances to write into this table. Sometimes, my ignite cluster is lagged if i try to create or drop other tables. Can anyone tell me why it happened, i can not find any information of this in ignite document.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behaviour. Creating or dropping table implies in turn a cache creation or destroy. It's required to run [partition map exchange](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/developers-guide/data-modeling/data-partitioning#partition-map-exchange) to create/destroy a cache. A PME routine will [wait](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/developers-guide/key-value-api/transactions#long-running-transactions-termination) for long-running transactions to finish preventing anything else to start.

I'd recommend to monitor a few PME [metrics](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/administrators-guide/monitoring-metrics/generic-metrics#partition-map-exchange) along with the [metrics](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/administrators-guide/monitoring-metrics/generic-metrics#transactions) related to transactions. It would give you insights about the reasons of a long PME execution.

Comment: Do you mean that my cluster is lagged because of data balancing? Cuz my application inserts data into cluster like a continuous process

Comment: But before it, i have many applications insert on this cluster too and i do not meet lagging

Comment: No, it's not because of rebalance, it's because of PME which sets a new data distributions (no actual transfers happen at that stage) and lets all the nodes know about it. PME needs to wait for ongoing transactions to finish.

Comment: But i can not explain why it only appears when run 1 application instead of others (they still insert as many as my app too) . Can u give me some prediction?

Comment: Share your logs for the corresponding time frame, we'll see what was going on.